# how to use multiple operator in case statement

Tags: mysql

This is my query :

```
select  user_id,
        relation,
CASE  WHEN ((select count(*) from family where personid_two = 5 AND relation = 'wife') > 0 OR (relation = 'daughter') > 1) THEN "true"
        ELSE "False" 
        END as result  
FROM  familyrelation 
WHERE user_id=5 AND personid_two=5 AND relation='daughter' 
limit 1;
```

This is my table:

```
 user_id | personid_two | relation    
-----------------------------------    
     5   |      5       |   wife       
     5   |      5       |   wife
     5   |      5       |  daughter
     5   |      5       |  daughter
     5   |      5       |  daughter
```

I am trying to fetch the value in such way that, if `daughter` row is more than two and `wife` row is more than one i should get result has false. I have used `or` condition to fetch the result. But when I run the query, I am not getting the appropriate result. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Expected output:

```
 user_id | personid_two | relation    |  result
------------------------------------------------    
     5   |      5       |   wife      | false
     5   |      5       |   wife      | false
     5   |      5       |  daughter   | false
     5   |      5       |  daughter   | false 
     5   |      5       |  daughter   | false
```

currently i am getting `true` for my above query. If the user gives wife or daughter, the query will check the table. If there is more than 1 rows in name of wife and 2 rows in daughter i should get 'false`.

Comment: Please provide the expected output in table format for the data you have given. Also explain why you use `OR` in your query but describe the rule using "and" in the last paragraph.

Comment: post your expected output to make it more clear

Comment: There aren't any personid_two = 5 in your sample so your code isn't going to find anything.Can you review please. Infact it's not clear to me why userid 5 has any relationship to any personid_two.

Comment: Can you please also explain what the output would be if last 2 "daughter" records would not have been there, and there would have been just 1? Would all remaining four records become true, or only the last one?

Comment: only the last record will become `false`, if there is only one `daughters' @trincot

Comment: You really mean `false`? Then I don't understand when they should be `true`. I assume you meant to say `true`, right?

Comment: Also, can you give an example where a `wife` record would get `true`? Or is a `wife` record always `false`?

Comment: Thankyou. But i solved the issue @trincot.

Comment: In that case, please close the question: either delete it, or mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(user_id int, personid_two int, relation varchar(10));
insert into t values    
 (    5   ,      5       ,  'wife')    ,   
 (    5   ,      5       ,  'wife'),
 (    5   ,      5       ,  'daughter'),
 (    5   ,      5       ,  'daughter'),
 (    5   ,      5       ,  'daughter');


select *,
        (select 
                    case when
                        sum(case when t1.relation = 'wife' then 1 else 0 end) > 1 and
                       sum(case when t1.relation = 'daughter' then 1 else 0 end) > 2 then 'false'
                    else 'true'
                    end
            from t t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id and t1.user_id = t1.personid_two
        ) trueorfalse
from t

+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| user_id | personid_two | relation | trueorfalse |
+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|       5 |            5 | wife     | false       |
|       5 |            5 | wife     | false       |
|       5 |            5 | daughter | false       |
|       5 |            5 | daughter | false       |
|       5 |            5 | daughter | false       |
+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```